# How can I one-hot encode a variable that has only 2 levels?

Tags: r, machine-learning, categorical-encoding, caret

I'm trying to do OHC in R to convert categorical into numerical data. However R's caret package requires one to use factors with greater than 2 levels. Any idea how to go around this? I've searched and not found a solution. I would do label encoding for instance but that would defeat the whole purpose of OHC. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the [`caret::dummyVars` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/dummyVars) not do what you need ?

Comment: It doesn't. I have factors with only 2 and some with onlly 1 level. The `dummyVars` function requires greater than 2 factors. I did not want to discard these columns.

Comment: Just recode as 0/1 numeric yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-hot encoding is commonly used in pre-processing data as inputs to machine learning algorithms. For factors with more than 2 levels, this involves creating one or more dummy variables. If a factor has only 2 levels then no dummy variables are needed - indeed it may be *already* one-hot encoded. Just check the levels (for example in R, use `levels(varname)`). If they are not 0 and 1, then just change them to 0 and 1 and you should be good to go. An example in R:

```
> x <- factor(c("alpha","beta","alpha","beta","alpha","beta"))
> length(x)
[1] 6

> x
[1] alpha beta  alpha beta  alpha beta 
Levels: alpha beta

> levels(x) <- c(0,1)
> x
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1
Levels: 0 1
```

You also mentioned factors with only 1 level. Such factors are not variables and could be removed from the dataset (as they are constants and will not affect predictions), but if it were me I would investigate *why* a single-factor variable is there in the first place.

Comment: That solved it, how would I automate it if many factors have only two levels though?

Comment: Something like this: `newData <- lapply(oldData[, the.vars], function(x) {levels(x) <- c(0,1)})` where `the.vars` are the column numbers